# Prevent breaking Syntax when using single quote in php

Tags: php

I have a php file that contains html. In the php file I echo sections of the html(Not the best way I know, but good for the time being).

I have started to apply AngularJs to this project and I am having a few problems with the syntax breaking in php.

for example ...

```
            echo="
            <!-- AngularJS -->
            <div class='container' style='border: 1px solid black'>
                <div class='row' ng-app='productsApp' ng-controller='ProductsController'>

                     <div ng-repeat='product in products | orderBy : product.id | limitTo : 3' class='col-md-4' style='border: 1px solid; padding: 20px;'>
                        <h4>{{ product.name }}<h4>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
          ";
```

So referring to the example above, i'd like to alter the html to ***orderBy : '-product.id'*** ... but the single quotes is causing syntax errors.

Can anyone advise how to get around this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What syntax errors? Where? For Angular? Why not use a HEREDOC string?

Comment: @temporalslide the error is being caused because it is breaking the echo statement of the php. I am essentially using the php echo function to print out the html, but when I apply the single quote, the php thinks I am closing the echo which makes the rest of the code unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When outputting blocks of text, prefer using HEREDOC/NOWDOC:

```
echo <<<'END'
    <!-- AngularJS -->
    Rest of HTML here
END;
```

This works well because you don't have to worry about nested quotes.

Comment: you should mention that the end tag of the heredoc ( newdoc in this case ) needs to be on its own line with not trailing spaces, or other characters...

Comment: this is what I was looking for, Thanks @ArtisiticPhoenix

Comment: Another alternative is to just drop out of PHP mode - `?> output stuff here <?php` works just fine.